# Como faço para criar uma legenda de determinado nome dentro de um <option> em um <select>?

Tags: php, html

Estou querendo fazer uma legenda dentro de um atributo `<option>` que crie uma legenda com o nome de um produto, como faço para exibir corretamente essa legenda?

O erro está na linha dentro do atributo `title=""`:

```
echo "<option title='{$v1['cd_produto']}'>{$v1['nome']}' value='{$v1['cd_produto']}'>{$v1['nome']}</option>";
```

O que retorna para mim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo:

```
<p> ID produto:
    <select onclick="buscaDados()" name="cd_produto" id="cd_produto" required="" title="Escolha a roupa">
        <option value="" title="Por padrão a opção é vazia, escolha abaixo o produto desejado"> Nenhum </option>
            <?php
                foreach ($resultado_produto as $v1) {
                    echo "<option title='{$v1['cd_produto']}'>{$v1['nome']}' value='{$v1['cd_produto']}'>{$v1['nome']}</option>";
                }
            ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Cara tem como colocar na pergunta um print do visual final que deve estar na tela?

Comment: Vou colocar um print pra você ver o que retorna.

Comment: @Xinante caso a resposta abaixo tenha resolvido seu problema, marque-a como resposta aceita para que possa ajudar outras pessoas também. Caso não, sinta-se à vontade para fazer um comentário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<select>
<option title="testando 1">teste 1</option>
<option title="testando 2">teste 2</option>
<option title="testando 3">teste 3</option>
</select>
```

O que está errado em seu código é com os fechamentos das aspas.

Tente tornar seu código mais simples, da seguinte forma:

```
<?php foreach($resultado_produto as $v1): ?>
    <option title="<?= $v1['cd_produto'] ?>" value="<?= $v1['cd_produto'] ?>"><?= $v1['nome'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Resolveu não cara, parece que não retorna o select com as chaves.

Comment: @Xinante o código que baixo que criei retorna como valor no formulário o campo `$v1['cd_produto']`. Para que quando o formulário seja enviado, deve ser adicionado o atributo "name" no `select`

Comment: Não tem como refazer não, ainda não funciona.

Comment: @Xinante o que não está funcionando explique mehor

Comment: Desculpe cara, o código funciona eu tinha digitado errado, mais agora funciona.